# Certificado de seguridad en android studio + Volley

Tags: android-studio, android-volley, certificado-ssl

Estoy usando el siguiente código para generar una instancia Singleton de la clase Volley e incorporarle un certificado de seguridad, el problema es que ahora necesito anexarle otro certificado y no tengo idea de donde hacerlo.

```
public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton instance;
private RequestQueue request;
private static Context context;

private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
    VolleySingleton.context = context;
    request = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (request == null) {
        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack(null, getSocketFactory()));
    }
    return request;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {

    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {

        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certcidi);
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.e("CERT", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);


        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                Log.e("CipherUsed", session.getCipherSuite());
                return hostname.compareTo("mobilecidi.cba.gov.ar") == 0; //The Hostname of your server.
            }
        };

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();

        return sf;

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Alguien podría orientarme?

Comment: El certificado a agregar sería para otro servidor cierto?

Comment: claro. seria para otro server y lo tengo guardado en la carpeta raw tambien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar otro certificado necestás:

1) El certificado X509 en formato `DER` en `res/raw` (similar al que ya está).

Si tenés el certificado en formato PEM (Se ve como texto con `--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--` y `--END CERTIFICATE--`) tenes que convertilo a formato der `DER`.

Una forma de hacerlo es con `openssl`:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificado2.pem -out certificado2.der
```

*Nota: certificado2.pem es el archivo con el certificado en formato PEM*

Luego el archivo `certificado2.der` hay que agregarlo al proyecto en Android Studio en `res/raw` junto con el otro certificado que tener ahí.

2) Crear una instancia de `Certificate` con ese certificado.

En `getSocketFactory()` replicar el bloque que crea que la instancia:

```
    cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certcidi);
    Certificate ca, ca2;
    try {
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        Log.e("CERT", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }

    caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certificado2);
    try {
        ca2 = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        Log.e("CERT", "ca2=" + ((X509Certificate) ca2).getSubjectDN());
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }
```

Con esto tenemos en `ca` el primer certificado y en `ca2` el segundo.

3) Guardar la instancia de Certificate en el KeyStore, junto con el que ya está.

Tambien en `getSocketFactory()`:

```
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca2", ca2);
```

4) Modificar el `hostNameVerifier()` para que valide el nombre del nuevo servidor.

Aca simplemente valido que el hostname informado coincida ya sea con el perimero o segundo server. 
   Tal vez se pueda mejorar de alguna forma para distinguir si la conexión es a uno u otro server pero no encontré una forma simple de obtener la url dentro de `verify()`.

```
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        Log.e("CipherUsed", session.getCipherSuite());

        return (hostname.compareTo("mobilecidi.cba.gov.ar") == 0 || 
                hostname.compareTo("nombre.esperado.2do.server.en.certificado") == 0); //The Hostname   of your server.
        }
};
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! ya lo pongo en prueba y comento como me fue

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo con la rta de Juan.

Dejo el código completo por si a alguien le sirve

```
public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton instance;
private RequestQueue request;
private static Context context;

private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
    VolleySingleton.context = context;
    request = getRequestQueue();
}

public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (request == null) {
        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack(null, getSocketFactory()));
    }
    return request;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

private SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {

    CertificateFactory cf = null;
    try {

        cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certcidi);
        Certificate ca, ca2;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.e("CERT", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        caInput = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certpaypertic);

        try {
            ca2 = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            Log.e("CERT", "ca2=" + ((X509Certificate) ca2).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca2", ca2);

        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                Log.e("CipherUsed", session.getCipherSuite());

                return (hostname.compareTo("mobilecidi.cba.gov.ar") == 0 ||
                        hostname.compareTo("a.paypertic.com") == 0);
            }
        };

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

        SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();

        return sf;

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

}